# Which regression should i use for the give structure ... its looks like logistic regression but when i tried not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

### i have Set of data the which looks like give below..

```
       C     D
0  1.920  1.81
1  1.925  1.76
2  1.940  1.71
3  1.950  1.68
4  1.955  2.24
```

i just draw the graph which looks like

[Scatter Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQD0s.png)

**Now i don't know which regression should i apply there..**

i tried Linear polynomial regression

and it looks like this..

[Scatter Graph After polynomial regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sc6Q.png)

Here is the ERRORS
(For training data)

```
RMSE: 0.18255431161685776
R2_SCORE: 0.0019985688907930843
```

### What i expect the graph should be

[What should i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkEMY.png)

Please help me out..
i'm in the big trouble..
Thank you so much

Comment: show us your code. You seems to swap the `x` and `y`, while building the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mixed up dependent and independent variable in your first two graphs and regression.

The expected outcome looks like 'D' should be the independent and 'C' the dependent variable while your graphs seem to have it the other way round.

Comment: no i did't do anything like this.. 
actually i din't get you.. can u explin me in more details please...

Comment: The scatter plot you posted has one set of data going upwards, and one set of data going downwards - at the same time. A single function cannot go up and down at the same time, so your curve fit is giving you a (mostly) flat line between the two.